# Unable to use PySide2

Tags: python, macos, pip, conda, pyside2

I'm trying to use PySide2 but I get the error code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide2'
```

I've already tried many things like re-installing etc. but it just won't work for some reason. When I checked my installs with `pip list` I can see that PySide2 5.15.2 is actually installed but I still can't import it.

I'm using Mac OS 10.15.7 and Python 3.5.8

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Python installed? If you still have (or had) Python 2, `pip` might be valid for that only, and you should use `pip3` instead.

Comment: When I try to install it with ```pip3 install PySide2```
I get this ```Requirement already satisfied: PySide2 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.15.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shiboken2==5.15.2 in /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from PySide2) (5.15.2)```

Comment: And how are you running your program?

Comment: I run it with the command ```python3 main.py```

Comment: The environment I'm using is ```Python 3.8.5 65-bit ('base': conda)```

Comment: to make sure you calling right pip; Does also `python3 -m pip list` output contains PySide2?